# Selecting from single dataset on multiple columns for a result with combined columns but multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, report, pivot

This problem hurts my head, probably because the database design itself could be better (such as having a single Column for storing the response to any question with multiple tables to map with multiple records of the same cert id).

This is what the table looks like and a sample record that I am trying to query from, essentially:

```
CERTIFICATIONID   EMPID       Q1_STATUS Q2_STATUS Q3_STATUS Q4_STATUS LAST_UPDATED
223             00001282122      1         0          1         1     2013-11-13 09:45:23.420
```

What I'd like to make happen with my query in the short term:

```
CERTIFICATIONID   EMPID       QUESTION ANSWER LAST_UPDATED
223             00001282122      1         1  2013-11-13 09:45:23.420
223             00001282122      2         0  2013-11-13 09:45:23.420
223             00001282122      3         1  2013-11-13 09:45:23.420
223             00001282122      4         1  2013-11-13 09:45:23.420
```

With these results, getting basically every *answer* as a result opposed to every *certification*, I could more easily make the query to generate a report (which would rely on another table which holds things like the Question prompt for a QUESTION id itself) which would look something like:

```
EMPID        QUESTIONPROMPT      2013-11-10    2013-11-11    2013-11-12    2013-11-13    2013-11-14    2013-11-15    2013-11-16    
00001282122 "Was good morning?"  NULL          NULL          NULL          1             NULL          NULL          NULL
00001282122 "Was good day?"      NULL          NULL          NULL          0             NULL          NULL          NULL

00001282122 "Was good evening?"  NULL          NULL          NULL          1             NULL          NULL          NULL

00001282122 "Was good night?"    NULL          NULL          NULL          1             NULL          NULL          NULL
```

Hopefully that describes the dilemma I'm faced with. I started to look into Joins, Pivots, etc.. and I'm just not sure what the best approach here would be. I don't really have the option of taking this Certification table, and splitting it out by all cert ids, and another table for question ids, and another table for making a proper many-to-many relationship between the two (a Cert ID may have multiple questions answered by a user in a single cert, and these same questions are also answered by other users and times in other Cert IDs).

So what do I do in a scenario like this, having to make a report from a database table that isn't as normalized and relational as it probably ought to be.

(edit) P.S-
I tried formatting the data into here as best I can, but is there a good way to bring in results from SQL Server into Stack Overflow in a manner that doesn't involve me adding spaces until everything looks somewhat right for next time, both for my own efficiency and for cleanliness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to obtain the first result...

```
SELECT 
CERTIFICATIONID, EMPID, LAST_UPDATED,
CASE WHEN X.QUESTION = 'Q1_STATUS' THEN 1
    WHEN X.QUESTION = 'Q2_STATUS' THEN 2
    WHEN X.QUESTION = 'Q3_STATUS' THEN 3
    WHEN X.QUESTION = 'Q4_STATUS' THEN 4
END [QUESTION],
ANSWER
FROM
( SELECT
    CERTIFICATIONID, EMPID, LAST_UPDATED, QUESTION,
    ANSWER
FROM 
   (SELECT *
   FROM CERTIFICATION_TABLE) T
UNPIVOT
   (ANSWER FOR QUESTION IN 
      (Q1_STATUS, Q2_STATUS, Q3_STATUS, Q4_STATUS)
)AS unpvt ) AS X
```

Comment: Wow, that's pretty incredible that this was answered so quickly and actually fit the bill perfectly for my primary concern. This should be a lot easier to work with from here.